# Memory allocation for simple variadic string concatenation in C

Tags: c, string, memory-management, variadic-functions

I have the following test function to copy and concatenate a variable number of string arguments, allocating automatically:

```
char *copycat(char *first, ...) {
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, first);
    char *result = (char *) malloc(strlen(first) + 1);
    char *next;
    strcpy(result, first);
    while (next = va_arg(vl, char *)) {
        result = (char *) realloc(result, strlen(result) + strlen(next) + 1);
        strcat(result, next);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Problem is, if I do this:

```
puts(copycat("herp", "derp", "hurr", "durr"));
```

it should print out a 16-byte string, `"herpderphurrdurr"`. Instead, it prints out a 42-byte string, which is the correct 16 bytes plus 26 more bytes of junk characters.

I'm not quite sure why yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't forget to call `va_end`.

Comment: Don't forget to `free` the returned string at some point.

Comment: Of course, it would be a shame not to ;D

Comment: Arrrggghhhh, Schlemiel has arrived ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm ) at `strlen(result) + strlen(next) + 1`

Comment: Rather than using `realloc`, you should walk the argument list twice, first to count the total length before allocation, then again to do the copying after allocation. This will be a lot more efficient and makes error handling trivial (there's now only one possible point of failure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable-argument-list functions don't magically know how many arguments there are, so you're most likely walking the stack until you happen to hit a `NULL`.

You either need an argument `numStrings`, or supply an explicit null-terminator argument after your list of strings.

Comment: Thanks! `puts(copycat("herp", "derp", "hurr", "durr", NULL));` works.

Comment: @R: Where is the memory leak?

Comment: @Oli: `malloc` if used in `copycat`. Where is the `free`?

Comment: Well, calling free() is obviously outside the scope of copycat(); if we freed the memory, how could we ever use the resulting string?

Comment: Passing the result to `puts` without saving it first is a memory leak. See OP's comment.

Answer (score 5):

You need a sentinel marker on your list:

```
puts(copycat("herp", "derp", "hurr", "durr", NULL));
```

Otherwise, `va_arg` doesn't actually know when to stop. That fact that you're getting junk is pure accident since you're invoking undefined behaviour. For example, when I ran your code as-is, I got a segmentation fault.

Variable argument functions, such as `printf` need some sort of indication as to how many items are passed in: `printf` itself uses the format string up front to figure this out.

The two general methods are a count (or format string) which is useful when you can't use one of the possible values as a sentinel (a marker at the end).

If you *can* use a sentinel (like NULL in the case of pointers, or -1 in the case of non-negative signed integers, that's usually better so you don't have to count the elements (and possible get the element count and element list out of step).

---

Keep in mind that `puts(copycat("herp", "derp", "hurr", "durr"));` is a memory leak since you're allocating memory then losing the pointer to it. Using:

```
char *s = copycat("herp", "derp", "hurr", "durr");
puts(s);
free (s);
```

is one way to fix that, and you may want to put in error checking code in case the allocations fail.

Answer (score 3):

What I understand from your code is that you assume va_next will return NULL once each argument has been "popped". That's wrong as va_next has absolutely no way to determine the number of arguments : your while loop will keep running until a NULL is randomly hit.

Solution : either provide the number of arguments, or add call your function with an additional "NULL" argument.

PS: if you are wondering why printf doesn't require such an additional argument, it's because the number of expected arguments is deduced from the format string (the number of '%flag')

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the other answers, you should cast the `NULL` to the expected type when using it as an argument to a variadic function: `(char *)NULL`. If NULL is defined as 0, then an int will be stored instead, which will accidentally work when int has the sime size as the pointer and NULL is represented by all bits 0. But none of this is guaranteed, so you may run into strange behaviour that's hard to debug when porting the code or even when only changing the compiler.

Comment: In C `NULL` is defined to be a `implementation defined null pointer constant` and in particular it is not just `0` as an integer. So this should not be necessary. (C++ redefines `NULL` to be `0`, but this is another story.)

Comment: @Jens: are you sure? Last I checked C defined `NULL` such that it would convert to the null pointer of the appropriate type implicitly in a pointer context, but that doesn't mean it's safe to pass `NULL` to variadic functions or functions with no prototype. It's certainly **not safe** if the required pointer type is anything but `void *` or `[[un]signed] char *`, as the representations could be different, but I'm not 100% sure it's unsafe in this particular case.

Comment: `#define NULL 0` is a valid definition of NULL. When given as a variadic argument then there is no pointer context, thus it is evaluated as an integer.

Comment: @R., @Secure: the wording that I used is the one from the definition in the C99 standard, 7.17. So according to that wording, I think, no, `#define NULL 0` would not be correct and that when used as an argument to a varg function it should, if it isn't already, be promoted to `void*`. What the business would be for C89, I don't know.

Comment: @Jens: From the C99 standard, 6.3.2.2 3: "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type 
void *, is called a null pointer constant."

Comment: @Secure: right. So in summary, this looks as yet another weird corner case. `NULL` being defined as a `null pointer constant` I would expect it to promote to a `void*` when placed on a va_arg list. But it seems that for pointers there even isn't such a promotion, they are just placed as is? At the end this would come that we should define ourselves a macro `SUPERNULL` as `(void*)NULL` which then is better phrased as `(void*)0`? This merits a defect report, I guess.

Comment: @Jens: There is neither weirdness nor any corner case. Don't be confused by the naming that contains "pointer". **An integer constant expression with the value 0** is a null pointer constant -- when used in a pointer context. But there simply isn't any context when used as an argument to a variadic function, so the type of the constant itself is used, which is int. That's all. By which declaration should the compiler decide if `0` means the int value 0 or the pointer value NULL? This has nothing to do with the promotion rules.

Comment: There is whole chapter in the C-FAQ dedicated to this: http://c-faq.com/null/index.html

Comment: @Secure: I insist in finding that weird :) You have just fallen in the same trap, by calling `NULL` a pointer value :) In the standard there is `null pointer` and `null pointer constant`. Yes indeed I was confused and thought that the latter would be just a constant expression of the former. What is even worse is that the standard allows `NULL` to be such a beast without a well defined type. With either one (`0` or `(void*)0`) would be ok, but allowing both and not specifying if an `int` or `void*` is put on the stack for a va_arg function is just crazy. I thought C is a typed language.

Comment: Please read the C FAQ, there is even a question why the null pointers are so confusing. ;) NULL **is** a pointer value -- when used in pointer context. The latter **is** just a constant expression of the former -- when used in pointer context. Problems arise only when there is no context available. Specifying int or void* would require a complete redefinition of variadic functions to allow this context. But even without context, the behaviour and type handling is well defined. Just a bit confusing. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, `va_arg` does not know when to stop. It is up to you to provide `NULL` (or some other marker) when you call the function. Just a few side notes:

- You must call `free` on pointers you obtain from `malloc` and `realloc`.
- There is no reason to cast the result of `malloc` or `realloc` in C.
- When calling `realloc`, it is best to store the return value into a temporary variable. If `realloc` is unable to reallocate enough memory, it returns `NULL` but the original pointer is **not** freed. If you use `realloc` the way you do, and it is unable to reallocate the memory, then you have lost the original pointer and your subsequent call to `strcat` will likely fail. You could use it like this:

  ```
  char *tmp = realloc(result, strlen(result) + strlen(next) + 1);
  if (tmp == NULL)
  {
      // handle error here and free the memory
      free(result);
  }
  else
  {
      // reallocation was successful, re-assign the original pointer
      result = tmp;
  }
  ```

Comment: Better to avoid `realloc` entirely. See my comment to OP's question.

Comment: @R..: Ultimately yes, it is a rather inefficient algorithm.